# TextWrangler does not work in Mac OS Catalina. Any workarounds?

Tags: macos-catalina, textwrangler

TextWrangler does not work in Mac OS Catalina. Do you know any tricks to get it working or are there good alternatives to TextWrangler?

Comment: You've been to [their home page](https://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/) where they say you can download BBEdit and use it for free? Besides, I'm not sure this question is really a great fit for stack-overflow, as it's not really about "programming".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

macOS Catalina will not run TextWrangler and there is no way to change that. (TextWrangler is a 32-bit app, and Catalina will not run 32-bit apps.)

However, BBEdit is built on a modernized (and 64-bit) version of the same core and it is the intended replacement. (BBEdit is free to use, just like TextWrangler was.)

You can find out more on the [TextWrangler product page](https://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/).